# Easy way to search & replace many word pairs in multiple files (Win & Linux)

Tags: text-editor

I have a map of values:

```
oldWord1 newWord1  
oldWord1 newWord1  
...  
oldWordn newWordn
```

In many files.

What is the easy way to replace them efficiently without manually doing search & replace for each pair?

I am looking for some simple tools or some hints how to do it using Eclipse, Vim , Notepad++ etc with the help of some scripting.

Answer (score 0):

SynWrite editor (Windows) can do scripting in Python. Write a py-plugin for this task, assign it a hotkey, and then call this plugin with hotkey.